# Radio/Checkbox Custom Background and Vertical-align

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I have a trouble with my radio buttons/checkboxes with custom backgrounds. I styled them like here : [Quick Tip: Easy CSS3 Checkboxes and Radio Buttons](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953). The main part is that input is behild label tag, other solutions of my topic suggest input to be inside label.

```
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_free_shipping" value="free_shipping" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
  <label for="shipping_method_0_free_shipping">DHL<span> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
  </label>
</li>
```

It is standart Woocommerce checkout shipping method choice. Here is how it looks : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ughmhbw6/)

It looks great on widescreen devices, but on mobiles label is settled on 2 lines, so I need to place checkbox image on center of `<li>`. I tried to apply vertical-align, but it don't center on whole `<li>` element. Maybe someone has encountered this problem?

Is should be like that

[image]

```css
ul#shipping_method {
    width: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#shipping_method li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3ced2;
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul#shipping_method li input {
  display: none;
}

ul#shipping_method li span {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}

ul#shipping_method li input + label:before {
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

ul#shipping_method li input + label:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '';
    margin-right: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#shipping_method li input:checked + label:before {
    background: url(http://s32.postimg.org/9rfrl1wlh/radio_checked.png) -1px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<ul id="shipping_method">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_free_shipping" value="free_shipping" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
    <label for="shipping_method_0_free_shipping">DHL<span> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate" value="flat_rate" class="shipping_method">
    <label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate">DHL Express - <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
    </label>         
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including radio button and label in a table as column elements,

```html
<li>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_free_shipping" value="free_shipping" class="shipping_method" checked="checked"></td>
    <td><label for="shipping_method_0_free_shipping">DHL<span> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
  </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</li>
```

Further you may need to edit css for your radio button.